# Python using Django Framework and Postgres Problems Connecting to Heroku Missing Modules

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models, heroku-postgres

I am having issues with an older project written with Django, now trying to push it to Heroku with issues. This was set up years ago with the same files by someone else in well under an hour. When I did it all day today, I originally got an error when launching and when running the logs I get:

```
bash: heroku: command not found
```

I hired 3 guys to help me that were "well-versed" in these areas. The first person knew quite a bit but came short on pip (pip freeze) and stated that the requirements.txt file was missing the required modules and he couldn't find which ones to include. So I set up a project on a freelance site specifically for someone to help me find modules and fix what's missing. I found a high rated vet with a great reputation specifically in Py/Django/Heroku who said he could help. I shared the exact same git repo I had and within 15 minutes he fixed the problem and shared with me on his localhost. **In hindsight I am wondering if he just so happened to have all the modules installed already**, being a fulltime Django developer for 6 years? Once I told him how important this is (I am in interview process for an amazing job that wanted to see a postgreSQL example project from my past) he quadrupled the price and held the files hostage.

I hired another Heroku/Django experienced freelancer and showed them everything in advance. He said he could definitely do it but then ran into issues he said with the profile requirements.txt again and my manage.py file which contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "vote.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

He then just blocked me and ghosted. I checked the postgres in heroku and it seems fine, the problem I believe is with finding the modules used if I'm not mistaken? The thing is all guys had the same files/repo and I know at least two got it working with current repo!?

Thanks guys!